# Why doesn't cron successfully run my bash script

Tags: bash, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a cron job listed in the root user's crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/service_monitor.sh
```

The contents of the file are below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -e


/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet nginx && aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name hearbeat-nginx --namespace heartbeat --value 1 --region eu-west-1
/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet prosody && aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name heartbeat-prosody --namespace hearbeat --value 1 --region eu-west-1
```

The file is executable and when I run it directly as root it runs with no issues and I get the metric recorded in AWS CloudWatch so I know there is no issues with the AWS cli or permissions.  However, when I try to run it as a cron job I don't see any metrics created.   I can see the file is being executed by cron in the syslogs. Any ideas?

Comment: does root's `.profile` or `.bashrc` set any environment variables needed by the `aws` command? These scripts aren't run  by `cron`, so the environment won't be set up correctly.

Comment: If the script produces any errors, they'll be sent to root's email. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws` may not be on the `PATH` passed to the environment of this program. As a best practice, consider either

- always referencing executables by absolute path in cron configuration files (easy to test) or
- always setting your `PATH` explicitly (more readable).

Also, you have a typo `hearbeat`.

Comment: Thank you, the full path to the AWS executable solved it!